# SharePoint - Modify the actions within a SPD-built workflow template programmatically?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer

Does anyone know whether it's possible to modify the workflow actions of a SharePoint Designer workflow template programmatically? For example, one has a SendEmail action and I'd like to modify the values of the To or the Bcc through code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've determined that this isn't possible. Closing question

Answer (score 0):

http://rshelton.com/archive/2008/01/04/how-to-adding-custom-workflow-activities-to-sharepoint-designer.aspx

Good luck